# Java: Syntax error on token "catch", ( expected

Tags: java, syntax, try-catch

I keep getting an error in the Eclipse IDE:

```
Syntax error on token "catch", ( expected
```

I'm not sure where the syntax error is, could someone help please?

```
public class ReadCSV {

    private static HashMap <String, String> rankDomainMap; 

    public ReadCSV() {
        rankDomainMap = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public HashMap getHashmap() {
        return rankDomainMap;
    }

    public void run(int id) {

        File top1m = new File("top-1m.csv");

        String line = "";

        int blockSize = 10000;

        try ( FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(top1m); BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader) )
            {
                while ( ((line = br.readLine()) != null) ) {
                    String parts[] = line.split(",");
                    for (int count=1; count < blockSize; count++){
                        if ( (Integer.parseInt(parts[0]) >= (id) ) && (Integer.parseInt(parts[0])+blockSize < id) ) {
                                rankDomainMap.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }


        System.out.println( rankDomainMap.toString() );

        catch (FileNotFoundException e)  {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did, repeatedly! It's driving me nutty!

Comment: If the indenting on the post matches your code then it would illustrate just how important code tabulation can be in your code especially for beginners. Double check all your indentation and braces and the issue should become very clear.

Answer (score 6):

catch has to directly follow the closing brace of the try.  Currently the code has a System.out.println.

It needs to look like this:

```
try {
    ......
}
catch(Exception e)
{
   .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `}` before the `catch`.